# Setting my PE Statistics as a sidebar on the right side

Tags: css, xenforo

I'm trying to have it so my forum statistics addon is moved to the right side of the forum instead of the bottom.

I've tried using a float as well positioning fix.
**Below is the whole small portion of the addon for my forum.**

```
<xen:require css="pe_forum_stats.css" />

<div class="nodeList sectionMain" id="peStatsContainer">
    <div class="peStatsBody">
        <div class="categoryStrip">
            <div class="categoryText">
                <h3 class="nodeTitle">{xen:phrase forum_statistics}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="peStatsContent">
                <div class="peStatsMembersOnline">
                        <xen:if is="{$onlineUsers.records}">
                            <xen:if is="{$visitor.user_id}">
                                <xen:if hascontent="true">
                                <div class="peFollowedOnline">
                                <h4 class="minorHeading"><a href="{xen:link account/following}">{xen:phrase people_you_follow}:</a></h4>
                                <ul class="followedOnline">
                                    <xen:contentcheck>
                                        <xen:foreach loop="$onlineUsers.records" value="$user">
                                            <xen:if is="{$user.followed}">
                                                <li title="{$user.username}" class="Tooltip"><xen:avatar user="$user" size="s" img="true" class="_plainImage" /></li>
                                            </xen:if>
                                        </xen:foreach>
                                    </xen:contentcheck>
                                </ul>
                                </div>
                                <h4 class="minorHeading"><a href="{xen:link members}">{xen:phrase members}:</a></h4>
                                </xen:if>
                            </xen:if>

                            <ol class="listInline">
                                <xen:foreach loop="$onlineUsers.records" value="$user" i="$i">
                                    <xen:if is="{$i} <= {$onlineUsers.limit}">
                                        <li>
                                    <xen:if is="{$user.user_id}">   
                                                <a href="{xen:link members, $user}"
                                        class="username{xen:if '!{$user.visible}', ' invisible'}{xen:if {$user.followed}, ' followed'}"><xen:if is="{$xenOptions.peForumStatsRichUserName}">{xen:helper richUserName, $user}<xen:else />{$user.username}</xen:if></a><xen:if is="{$i} < {$onlineUsers.limit}">,</xen:if>
                                    <xen:else />
                                        {xen:phrase guest}<xen:if is="{$i} < {$onlineUsers.limit}">,</xen:if>
                                    </xen:if>
                                        </li>
                        </xen:if>
                            </xen:foreach>
                                <xen:if is="{$onlineUsers.recordsUnseen}">
                                    <li class="moreLink">... <a href="{xen:link online}" title="{xen:phrase see_all_visitors}">{xen:phrase and_x_more, 'count={xen:number $onlineUsers.recordsUnseen}'}</a></li>
                                </xen:if>
                        </ol>
                    </xen:if>
                <!-- <br /> Eh? -->
                    <div class="footnote">
                        <a href="{xen:link online}" title="{xen:phrase see_all_online_users}">{xen:phrase online_now_x_members_y_guests_z_robots_a, 'total={xen:number $onlineUsers.total}', 'members={xen:number $onlineUsers.members}', 'guests={xen:number $onlineUsers.guests}', 'robots={xen:number $onlineUsers.robots}'}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <xen:if is="{$xenOptions.peForumStatsLegend}">
                <ul class="peUserGroupLegend">
                    <xen:if hascontent="true">
                        <xen:contentcheck>
                            <xen:foreach loop="$peForumStatsLegend" value="$peForumStatsLegend">
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="peGroups" style="{$peForumStatsLegend.usergroup.username_css}" title="{$peForumStatsLegend.usergroup.user_title}">{$peForumStatsLegend.usergroup.title}<span class="divider">|</span></span>
                                    </li>
                            </xen:foreach>
                        </xen:contentcheck>
                    </xen:if>
                </ul>
            </xen:if>
        </div>

            <div id="peForumStats">
                <ul class="sectionFooter peList_inline">
                    <li>{xen:phrase discussions}:</li> <span class="value">{xen:number $boardTotals.discussions}</span>
                    <li>{xen:phrase messages}:</li> <span class="value">{xen:number $boardTotals.messages}</span>
                    <li>{xen:phrase members_count}:</li> <span class="value">{xen:number $boardTotals.users}</span>
                    <li>{xen:phrase latest_member}:</li> <span class="value"><xen:username user="$boardTotals.latestUser" /></span>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm hoping to have it appear at the right side of the forum and when I scroll down for it to not move at all.

Comment: Can you provide the forum link?

Comment: Is there a way to privately send it to you? @ManojKumar

Comment: It's actually because the link is an IP as I ain't got it covered yet so I didn't want to reveal it publicly. @ManojKumar

~ Sorry if it came off strange

Comment: Send me via https://manojkumar.online/contact/ Let me see if I can do that.

Comment: I’ve sent it, sorry for the troubles and thank you very much! @ManojKumar

Comment: Okay. I just saw your forum. Did you enable the sidebars? Try using some inbuilt widgets there so that a sidebar structure is formed.

Comment: I’m not so sure as it’s a custom add on and nothing to do with the default forum @ManojKumar

Comment: But if you enable the sidebar. The section would be visible and it would be easier to fit the stats into it.

Comment: Would it be possible to temporarily add you on discord or something for further help regarding it?

Comment: Okay. But if you have a Xenforo License, You can ask in their forum itself. Stack Overflow is very localised in this tag and hard to get answers. If you are using nulled, there are nulled Xenforo forums for your help too.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll go and use them :)